# Database and JTable

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть предложение поделиться примерами как вы синхронизируете измененные данные в JTable с базой данных, если подробнее то так: есть таблица в базе данных, есть таблица в приложении, вы закачиваете данные из базы в приложение и на месте их править, соответственно их надо обновить в базе, как вы храните id записи в таблице приложения. Выводить ее на всеобщее обозрение не кашерно так как может быть нарушена последовательность.
Может я усложняю и есть готовые стандарты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас возникает такая проблема потому, что у вас нет модели данных и вы пытаетесь делать так, как в дельфях было принято. Из-за этого возникают нелепые проблемы. Вам следует копать в сторону [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) и [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). Тогда вы сможете использовать любые свои классы в качестве строк и в них уже хранить всё что вы хотите, а отображение этих строк - вопрос отдельный.

Примеров на тему масса. Вот хотя бы первая же ссылка из документации по TableModel: [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: Ок, я раньше массивами обходился, гляну про TableModel)

Comment: Массивы кажутся простым решением, но на деле они запутывают всё и делают модификацию сложной. Используйте отдельные классы для строк таблицы - это наглядно и удобно.

Comment: А как с производительностью, допустим у меня таблица на 50 тысяч заявок, я соображу что все выводить глупо, а пользователь обычный... сильно загрузит память?

Comment: 50 тысяч - это фигня. А если не фигня, то у вас ведь TableModel в распоряжении: используйте lazy load и какое-нибудьй постепенное уничтожение строк. Вам ведь не обязательно создавать все экземпляры строк, вам надо только их количество заранее сообщить, а отдельные экземпляры таблица сама у вас спросит по мере надобности.

Comment: Оки-доки, просвятил)

Comment: Кроме того, можно применить паттерн проектирования "приспособленец", чтобы снизить нагрузку на память.

Comment: ок, чувствуется опыт)